# How to filter out elements from a list of dictionaries with repeating keys and different values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `list` of repeating `dict`. I want to filter out a few elements of each `dict`. I can do this by looping through the entire `list`, and select the wanted elements, as shown in the below example. However, this doesn't seem like an efficient method. What is the best way of achieving the desired result, as outputted below, in terms of memory usage and speed?

```
listOfDic = [
      {'firstElement': 'a', 'secondElement': '1', 'thirdElement': 'i'}
    , {'firstElement': 'b', 'secondElement': '2', 'thirdElement': 'ii'}
    , {'firstElement': 'c', 'secondElement': '3', 'thirdElement': 'iii'}
]
filteredListOfDic = []

# looping through old list, selecting first and third element
# and using those elements for building a new "filtered" list of dict
for row in listOfDic:
    filteredListOfDic.append({
          'firstElement': row['firstElement']
        , 'thirdElement': row['thirdElement']
    })

print filteredListOfDic
```

The result being:

```
[{'thirdElement': 'i', 'firstElement': 'a'}
, {'thirdElement': 'ii', 'firstElement': 'b'}
, {'thirdElement': 'iii', 'firstElement': 'c'}]
```

Comment: In terms of memory it should be list of dictionaries that have 2 elements , it won't be any approach to achieve better memory usage. and it term of speed you should go through all elements and select desired ones , it is _O(n)_ anyway , but maybe there should be a approach with little improving performance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a simple `del` would be enough to delete the elements from each dictionary, instead of copying the desired elements.

```
for l in listOfDic:
    del l["secondElement"]

>>> print listOfDic
>>> [{'thirdElement': 'i', 'firstElement': 'a'}, {'thirdElement': 'ii', 'firstElement': 'b'}, {'thirdElement': 'iii', 'firstElement': 'c'}]
```

Comment: done some benchmarks, and deletion is the fastest method, as far as i can see. but nice alternative from @zwer, if the original `dict` should be kept. written a test, that uses the method from @zwer and @JonClements as well. the results are, when doing `1.000.000 loops:` - 
`original method     : 1.43119890333s` - `list comprehension a: 1.24798784415s` - `list comprehension b: 1.93964952847s` - `deletion            : 0.71917023139s`

Comment: note: for benchmarking deletion with list comprehension, the test was changed in comparison to just benchmarking the two list comprehension methods. hence different numbers than below.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep your dictionaries, you can create a new one using simple list comprehension:

```
filteredListOfDic = [{"firstElement": row["firstElement"], "thirdElement": row['thirdElement']} for row in listOfDic]
```

**EDIT:** For those suspicious of performance gain when using list comprehension:

```
#time: original_method() - 1,000,000 loops: 1.10493s
#time: lst_comp_method() - 1,000,000 loops: 0.79917s
```

That's almost 40% faster.

Comment: Might even want to consider something like: `[{k: d[k] for k in ('firstElement', 'thirdElement')} for d in listOfDic]` which puts the keys names in a single place and removes the need to repeat them for each key/value.

Comment: @JonClements - I was toying with that idea, but while that would make it easier to read (and control) it will also make it about ten times slower (an additional loop + tuple creation for each element). Given that the OP's primary concern was memory usage and speed, nice dynamic solutions are not really an answer ;)

Comment: thanks! nice input. i continued, doing some more timing tests. here are the results, when doing 1.000.000 loops: `original_method: 0.935705815317s` - `lst_comp_method: 0.750181842205s` and `2nd_comp_method: 1.40672337193s`